# Does the equality of map of stalks imply the equality of the map of global sections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $X$ be a  scheme and $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $f,g: X \to \operatorname{Spec}{R}$ be morphisms of schemes. Suppose I know that $f(x) = g(x)$ and $f^{\#}_x = g^{\#}_x$ for all $x \in X$, where 
$$
f^{\#}_x, g^{\#}_x: R_P/(P R_P) \to O_{X, x}/m_x
$$
the induced map on the residue fields. Does is then follow that 
$f^{\#} = g^{\#}$? where $f^{\#}$ and  $g^{\#}$ are maps of the global sections
$$
R \to \Gamma(X, O_X). 
$$
Thank you!

Comment: We certainly have to assume that $f,g$ induce the same map on the level of topological spaces for this question to make sense. Then this should hold if $X$ is reduced (I can provide a proof if you'd like)

Comment: Proof would be appreciated, thank you! Also I added the assumption I forgot to state.

Comment: Is there a counter example when $X$ is not reduced?